# How does WiFiKill actually work?

Tags: wi-fi

There is a program for Android, [WifiKill](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1282900), which disables wifi internet access of some neighbor peers connected to the same wifi AP. How does this program works? ARP poisoning or some other techniques?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The app's author himself explains how it works at the top of the [second page of that thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1282900&page=2) you linked to:

> It's the same idea as FaceNiff (I'm a developer of it also), basically
>   it sends ARP Reply's to all of the devices in the network fooling them
>   to think that your mobile is router. And then all of the devices try
>   connecting to network THROUGH your device... and you just drop every
>   single packet from them. In this version it's just dropping packets
>   but maybe later I'll try adding some sort of primitive REJECT target.

[And slightly more on page 5](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1282900&page=5)

> > Originally Posted by Jufjufjuf
> >
> > Is this using an arpspoofing attack? Just wondering if there was anyway to send out de-auth packets through android like airdrop-ng?
>
> Yes, it's using arp spoofing. I suppose there is a way to send deauth
>   packets but it would require modifying kernel drivers for wifi card.
>   AFAIK it won't work out-of-the-box because most of android wifi
>   drivers don't allow packet injections and even changing the mac
>   address of the NIC is super-difficult in a lot of devices.

As far as tools for desktop OSs go, there are a few that will do this kind of thing, MDK3 seems to be a popular one for [doing this kind of thing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVjfjU8H_hc).